# Unable to install a shared library in yocto

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, embedded-linux, yocto

I wrote a recipe to build a shared library. Here is the recipe

```
SUMMARY = "test library"
SRC_URI = " file://file1.c \
            file://file2.c \
            file://internal.h" 

LICENSE = "CLOSED"
FILES_${PN} = "libtest.so"
do_compile() {
    ${CC} -fPIC -c ${WORKDIR}/file1.c -o ${WORKDIR}/file1.o
    ${CC} -fPIC -c ${WORKDIR}/file2.c -o ${WORKDIR}/file2.o
    ${CC} -shared -o ${WORKDIR}/libesys.so ${WORKDIR}/file1.o ${WORKDIR}/file2.o 
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/libtest.so ${D}${libdir}/
}
```

It fails with the following errors:

```
ERROR: test-0.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: -dev package contains non-symlink .so: test-dev path '/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/test/0.1-r0/packages-split/test-dev/usr/lib64/libtest.so' [dev-elf]
ERROR: test-0.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: No GNU_HASH in the elf binary: '/home/jamal/repotest1/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/test/0.1-r0/packages-split/test-dev/usr/lib64/libtest.so' [ldflags]
ERROR: test-0.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: test-0.1-r0 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/jamal/repotest1/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/test/0.1-r0/temp/log.do_package_qa.20989
ERROR: Task (/home/jamal/repotest1/sources/meta-test/recipes-support/test/test_0.1.bb:do_package_qa) failed with exit code '1'
```

Can you please help me in to find out the issue.. Appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Default packaging rules assumes that libraries are versioned, and your libraries are not.

Either install versioned libraries, or if you really don't want to https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/Packaging_Prebuilt_Libraries#Non-versioned_Libraries shows you how to manipulate the rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://greetings.c \
                   file://greetings.h \
                   "
S = "${WORKDIR}"
TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"

#INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
#INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"
SOLIBS = ".so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""

do_configure () {
                # Specify any needed configure commands here
                :
}

do_compile () {
        ${CC} -fPIC -c ${WORKDIR}/greetings.c -o ${WORKDIR}/greetings.o
        ${CC} -shared -o ${WORKDIR}/libtest.so ${WORKDIR}/greetings.o 
        #g++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so.1 -o libtest.so.1.1.0
}


do_install () {
        install -d ${D}${libdir}
        install -d ${D}${includedir}
#oe_soinstall ${WORKDIR}/libtest.so ${D}${libdir}
        install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/libtest.so ${D}${libdir}
        install -m 0755 ${S}/*.h ${D}${includedir}
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.